# Producer-Consumer model

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, producer-consumer

I'm trying to simulating the producer-consumer model about multithreading.

We assume that there three rules to obey:

1. Producer can not add product into the bucket when the bucket is full of products.
2. Consumer can not get product from the bucket when the bucket is empty.
3. Producing and Consuming can not take place at the same time. In other words, the two actions are asynchronous.

Now what I have:

1. a `int` varible to store the count of products in the bucket
2. a `const int` variable for the capacity of the bucket, which is valued as 5 in my code.
3. a `int` variable for mutex, whose initial value is 1
4. a `vector<HANDLE>` variable for suspended handle, and there will be a function scheduling these suspended threads.

**The result is: Sometimes it work fine, but sometimes it becomes a deadlock. The code and results are as follows:**

**code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// the count of product, the initial value is 0
int product_count = 0;

const int product_capacity = 5;

int mutex = 1;

vector<HANDLE> suspendedHandleVector;

HANDLE GetCurrentRealHandle() {
    HANDLE realHandle = 0;
    return OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, GetCurrentThreadId());
}

void ThreadScheduling() {
    if (suspendedHandleVector.size() > 0) {
        HANDLE handle = suspendedHandleVector[0];
        suspendedHandleVector.erase(suspendedHandleVector.begin());
        ResumeThread(handle);
    }
}

void P() {
    --mutex;
    if (mutex < 0) {
        auto handle = GetCurrentRealHandle();
        suspendedHandleVector.push_back(handle);
        SuspendThread(handle);
    }
}

void V() {
    ++mutex;
    if (mutex >= 0) {
        ThreadScheduling();
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ProducerThread(LPVOID param) {
    while (true) {
        P();
        if (product_count == product_capacity) {
            V();
            continue;
        }
        ++product_count;
        cout << "I'm producer, and there are " << product_count << " products now" << endl;
        V();
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ConsumerThread(LPVOID param) {
    while (true) {
        P();
        if (product_count == 0) {
            V();
            continue;
        }
        --product_count;
        cout << "I'm consumer, and there are " << product_count << " products rest now" << endl;
        V();
        Sleep(150);
    }
    return 0;
}

void main() {
    auto producer_handle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, ProducerThread, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    auto consumer_handle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, ConsumerThread, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    while (true) {
        cout << suspendedHandleVector.size() << endl; // This is for debugging
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

**the result when it work as expected:**

```
0
I'm producer, and there are 1 products now
I'm consumer, and there are 0 products rest now
0
I'm producer, and there are 1 products now
I'm consumer, and there are 0 products rest now
0
I'm producer, and there are 1 products now
0
I'm consumer, and there are 0 products rest now
I'm producer, and there are 1 products now
0
I'm producer, and there are 2 products now
I'm consumer, and there are 1 products rest now
```

**And this is a expected infinite loop. The product-count will flow at 4 and 5 because I set the producer to sleep a little more time than consumer.**

**But here is the unexpected result:**

```
I'm producer, and there are 5 products now
I'm consumer, and there are 4 products rest now
0
I'm consumer, and there are 4 products rest now
I'm producer, and there are 5 products now
0
0
I'm consumer, and there are 4 products rest now
I'm producer, and there are 5 products now
0
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

**As we see, the size of the suspended thread vector reached 2 from 0, which leaving out 1.**

**Is this just a coincident where the two threads were waken up at the same then being a conflict?**

**I consider something wrong with my code more, which needs your help.**

I also got a problem during testing: How can I get the thread and then store it in the vector.

I am not sure about using `OpenThread` to do this. My course asked me to use system call so I did'nt include `thread` headfile.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is really well known patterrn... Just look how to implement the producer-consumer-queue... You can create a thread safe queue... The queue should have a blocking method `pop` so the consumer can wait until a new item arrives in the queue. The consumer just `push` elements into the queue... Don't mess your code with that locks and mutex

Comment: And it's sad to see that courses avoid C++ library... most of them is teaching how to don't code :'(

Comment: @elvis.dukaj a lot of these classes aren't to teach C++, they're to teach CS concepts *using* C++. The problem is that students enter with no knowledge of how C++ works, so they're stuck learning the regular class material (data structures or whatever) AND having to fend for themselves when it comes to learning C++. There really should be a programming bootcamp at universities that's a prerequisite. Teach how to use C++, Java, and let's say Python? Whatever the professors want. But that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes it's from OS course, but how can it avoid c/c++ when it comes to operation system right? I do plan to spend some time learning cpp, but I think it will be a long fight.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Thank you for your advice! But in fact this scope of code is just for test and a better understanding of threads. I even didn't take any consideration to `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Well I don't wanna to be too much out of scope... but learning CS topics requires basic fundamentals in programming language... it makes no sense explain concept without knowing the language.
People that comes out from this class are completely not prepared for the real world.
It's like learning a poem without knowing the basic grammar...

Comment: @elvis.dukaj That is indeed an issue. But I think the professors just doesn't want the students complete it by calling some well-encapsulation methods. This will make it difficult for students to understand what is happening behind those methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the producer-consumer problem there are three actors: the producer, the consumer and a buffer used to store the produced data. The producer and the consumer usually are living in one or more thread (multi-producer single-consumer single-producer multi-consumer multi-producer multi-consumer).

Now this pattern is very used because it's one of the way to avoid explicit synchronization.

As I said the consumer and the consumer usually lives in one ore more threads. The buffer usually is a synchronized queue (can be both locked queue or lock-free).

A very short snippet:

```cpp
SyncronizedQueue queue;

void consumer()
{
  while(1) {
    queue.push(std::rand());
  }
}

void producer()
{
    while(1)
    {
      auto product = queue.pop();   // blocks until there are elements in the 
    }
}

void main()
{
  std::thread producerThread{producer};
  std::thread consumerThread{consumer};

  producerThread.join();
  consumerThread.join();
}
```

So the task is to write the queue so that is safe `push` elements and unlock `pop` when a new element is pushed.

One simple way to implement is to use conditional variables so the `pop` function is blocked until a condition is fired and the push method add an element to the queue and fire the condition.